# Route annotations from yml file was not working in openshift

Tags: kubernetes, routes, openshift, openshift-client-tools, openshift-enterprise

We are using openshift for the deployment where we have 3 pods running with same service

To achieve load balancing we are trying to create a annotations in the route.

Adding annotations in  Route from console it is working fine

But the same is not working if I configured from yml file.

Is anyone facing the same issue or any available fix for this

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Route
metadata:
  annotations:   
  
  haproxy.router.openshift.io/balance : roundrobin

 
 haproxy.router.openshift.io/disable_cookies: true

  name: frontend
spec:
  host: www.example.com
  path: "/test" 
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: frontend
```

Answer (score 0):

This annotation doesnt work like this. This is used when route is distributing traffic among many services not just one as in your case.

https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/architecture/networking/routes.html#alternateBackends

Service in OpenShift or Kubernetes is nothing but a kube-proxy which works at TCP L4 level and provides default round robin load balancing to backend pods.

https://blog.getambassador.io/load-balancing-strategies-in-kubernetes-l4-round-robin-l7-round-robin-ring-hash-and-more-6a5b81595d6c